# File write triggering multiple times in Wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a simple hit counter shortcode in Wordpress using a text file and I have found out that it is somehow triggering the file write process multiple times.

```
function sc_page_counter() {
    $fname = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/counter.txt";

    if (!file_exists($fname)) {
        file_put_contents($fname, "0");
    }

    $ct = file_get_contents($fname);
    file_put_contents($fname, ++$ct);

    return $ct;
}
add_shortcode('page_counter', 'sc_page_counter');
```

I have put the shortcode call in my footer.php

```
This site has been visited <?php echo do_shortcode('[page_counter]') ?> times.
```

Let's say the current content of counter.txt is 20. The shortcode will correctly output "21" but upon checking the counter.txt file. It is now "25". Results vary whether I'm running it locally or in the production server.

I tried testing it further by just appending a character instead of writing the new value and it appended it about 32 times. I'm currently stumped on why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try adding it in any page/post?

Comment: No, it is only called in the footer area. I did try and do it so it was not a shortcode and called only the function but it's still doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use shortcode for this. Second, write to the database.

Site views:

`functions.php` of your theme:

```
function header_stuff()
{
    $site_views = get_option('site_views');
    update_option('site_views', (((preg_match('#^\d+$#', $site_views)) ? $site_views : 0) + 1));
}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_stuff');
```

`footer.php`

```html
This site has been visited <?php echo get_option('site_views') ?> times.
```

Or, if you'd like to see views of single post/page page, you can use the following:

`functions.php` of your theme:

```
function header_stuff()
{
    global $post;
    if (is_object($post) && is_singular())
    {
        $post_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_views', true);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_views', (((preg_match('#^\d+$#', $post_views)) ? $post_views : 0) + 1));
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_stuff');
```

Output where you need it:

```
if (is_object($post) && is_singular())
{
    echo 'Views: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, '_views', true);
}
```

Or you can count them both if you need that:

```
function header_stuff()
{
    //Site view
    $site_views = get_option('site_views');
    update_option('site_views', (((preg_match('#^\d+$#', $site_views)) ? $site_views : 0) + 1));

    //Post view
    global $post;
    if (is_object($post) && is_singular())
    {
        $post_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_views', true);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_views', (((preg_match('#^\d+$#', $post_views)) ? $post_views : 0) + 1));
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_stuff');
```

Comment: Thank you for the better method. However, even this method ended up triggering the update method multiple times. I am now very confused why the update triggers more than once.

Just note that I have disabled plugins to check if they might be causing it.

Comment: @EddryanAranzans, unless `wp_head` is called multiple times, multiple updates simply can't happen. Can you share your resulting code on say pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0249WCRV but it looks like I found the reason why it's firing off multiple times. There are missing assets being loaded causing the additional triggers. I removed the references and it is now working properly. Thanks you very much!